# Using awk to edit and save all numeric values in one column (field)

Tags: awk, numeric

I have a large file, and I would like to use `awk` to edit all the numeric values in the second row of the file. I do not need to search for a pattern, just add a specified number to all the numbers that are already there. Also save this changes to a new file.

For example:

Oldfile.pdb

```
step 1 blabla
step 2 blabla
step 3 blabla
step 4 blabla
```

add 5 to all values in column 2

newfile.pdb

```
step 6 blabla
step 7 blabla
step 8 blabla
step 9 blabla
```

Comment: The solution to `save this changes to a new file` is the same for all UNIX commands: `cmd file > tmp && mv tmp file`. Oh sure a couple of tools might have an option to do what they call "inplace editing" but none of them actually do that, they all use a tmp file internally (except `ed` which uses a buffer instead of a file) so using that option saves you a couple of characters typing, that's all.

Answer (score 4):

just to be exhaustif in case second column is exactly, unhopefully, the opposite of the value to add, but solution of @A-Ray is normally good enough

```
awk '{$2+=5;print}' YourFile
```

Answer (score 0):

awk:

```
awk '$2+=5' file
```

.........

Comment: Came here to post the same. This will work in all `awk`s; no need to single out `gawk`.

Comment: Yeah.   So accustomed to writing

Comment: This is a bit dangerous as @NeronLeVelu points out. Any lines where `$2` has the value `-5` will be excluded from the output. Maybe not a problem depending on what is known about the input, but always something to keep in mind when using the pattern for side-effects.

Comment: Don't rely on `$2+=5` producing a non-zero result, use `awk '{$2+=5}1' file` instead.

Comment: Thanks. Did not consider all possibilities

Answer (score 0):

To save the changes with the required operations done from Oldfile.pdb to newfile.pdb :

```
awk '{$2=$2+5; print $0}' Oldfile.pdb > newfile.pdb
```